# Videos and visual tutorials on Format String Vulnerabilities

Tags: exploit, known-vulnerabilities

Anyone know of good format string vulnerability tutorials/videos that demo how to test on a web app, such as modifying the URL. I've watched Vivek's videos from securitytube and another from CarolinaCon, but am looking for a more detailed/visual demo of how to apply it in web app pen-testing. In addition, I have seen other vulnerable web apps such as Damn Vulnerable Web App and Webgoat, as well as a few others, but can't seem to find how an attacker can exploit a format string vulnerability via a web browser and how to protect against it, other than modifying the code of the vulnerable link and/or program.

This all stems from reading different external scanning reports that always seem to contain Format String Vulnerability located at www.domainname.com/default.asp?(insert name here and code, ex.) News=%2508x. What exactly should I be looking for and how is someone supposed to investigate/test this (tools, manual, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

The [OWASP Testing Guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Format_String) has some guidance, as well as some whitepapers and references to tools.

WASC has [this](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246926/Format%20String) entry.

There scanning tools that look for this kind of vulnerability. w3af has a [formatString](http://w3af.sourceforge.net/plugin-descriptions.php#formatString) plug-in that might help you test, depending on your application's setup.

Other than these things, I assume you learned from the videos to test for printf formatting characters. If you add these characters to a dictionary and fuzzing attack on inputs, you can determine the vulnerability of the application, if not exploit the vulnerability.

Answer (score -1):

Check The [Defcon Conference Videos](http://www.defcon.org/), I am sure There are some videos about what you want.